# Find optimal linear fit in a moving window

Tags: performance, r, linear-regression

**The task:** Find the slope of the best linear fit (e.g., minimize error variance) in a moving window. x values are equidistant, e.g. automatic measurements over time.

**The problem:** Performance is an issue, because it needs to be repeated for many datasets.

**The naive implementation:** Loop over the y values.

```
#some data
x <- 0:(8*60)
set.seed(42)
y <- -x^2*0.01+x*20+rnorm(8*60+1,mean=300,sd=50)

plot(y~x,pch=".")

optWinLinFit0 <- function(x,y,win_length) {
  xfit <- x[seq_len(win_length)]
  xfit <- xfit-min(xfit)
  #regression on moving window
  res <- lapply(seq_len(length(x)-win_length),function(i,x,y) {
    y <- y[seq_len(win_length)+i-1]
    list(y=y,fit = lm.fit(cbind(1,xfit),y))    
  },x=x, y=y)
  #find fit with smallest sigma^2
  winner <- which.min(sapply(res,function(x) 1/(win_length-2)*sum(x$fit$residuals^2)))

  y <- res[[winner]]$y
  #return fit summary and predicted values
  list(n=winner,summary=summary(lm(y~xfit)),
       dat=data.frame(x=x[-seq_len(winner-1)][seq_len(win_length)],
                      y=y,
                      ypred=res[[winner]]$fit$fitted.values))
}
res0 <- optWinLinFit0(x,y,180)


lines(ypred~x,data=res0$dat,col="red",lwd=2)
```

The red line gives the fitted values in the position of the moving window, where the error variance is minimal:
[image]

Any ideas how to do this faster?

Comment: I really don't understand the downvote here! +1 from me.

Comment: Actually I might take that back - I think this needs more explanation on what the problem is. For example, in the code shown, the covariate is always the first `win_length` values of `x`. In my mind a moving window would fit the values of `y` in some range of `x`, moving that window across `x`. Here `x` seems fixed. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @GavinSimpson As stated in the question, x values are equidistant and we are only interested in the slope (or more precisely the gradient). That means we can simplify the problem by fixing x. This is a common approach for flux calculation from measurements of soil respiration. (There are people who still use Excel to do this.)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. The way you worded it a locally linear model sprang to mind. I haven't had chance to run the code, but I don;'t see the relationship between the red line in the figure and the "moving window". Guess I don't understand what you mean by a "moving window". In this context. On a more general level, it is all well and good to ask and answer your own question, but as it stands, without more explanation this could be deemed too localized. Just because you understand what this means doesn't mean someone else will - more discussion will may it more relevant.

Comment: What I'm getting at, in a moving window approach that I am familiar with, you would have an estimate of the slope for chunks across `x`. Why no estimate of gradient around `x == 300`? What is so special about the bit indicated in the "red" line? That is what I think you need to explain.

Comment: The red line is the fitted values over the position of the moving window that gave the best fit. You can move `x` with `y`, but that should give exactly the same fit. Think of it as shifting the `x` values, so they start with 0 for each of the fits (and shifting them back afterwards).

Answer (score 2):

You're basically doing a [kernel regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression). There are lots of functions and packages designed for this: `KernSmooth`, `gam` and `locfit` come to mind. In base R, there is also `loess` (and `lowess`, an older version). More broadly, package `mgcv` does the same thing, but using a different splines-based approach.

For what you're doing, I'd use either `gam::gam` or `mgcv::gam` and use finite differences on predictions on a grid. Only the former is based on an actual local regression, but they both answer the question being asked.

I don't see the need to reinvent the wheel. More importantly, using existing packages means that you'll be taking into account issues like bias at the endpoints, and at turning points in the curve (a local linear fit will be biased around a local maximum/minimum); weighting schemes to use; etc. You can also take advantage of the standard tools for model-building and checking, like cross-validation and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to call `lm` only once with a matrix of responses. This is faster by a factor of 2, but assumes that y values are non-zero. If zero values are possible, you could check for that and use `optWinLinFit0` as a fall-back.

```
optWinLinFit1 <- function(x,y,win_length) {
  xfit <- x[seq_len(win_length)]
  xfit <- xfit-min(xfit)

  #get all windows of values in one matrix
  mat <- outer(y,rep(1,length(y)))

  require(Matrix)
  mat <- band(mat,k1=0,k2=win_length-1)
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  mat <- mat[,-(1:win_length-1)]
  nc <- ncol(mat)
  mat <- matrix(mat[mat!=0],ncol=nc)

  #regression with response matrix
  fit <- lm.fit(cbind(1,xfit),mat)

  #find fit with smallest sigma^2
  winner <- which.min(1/(win_length-2)*colSums(fit$residuals^2))

  y <- mat[,winner]
  #return fit summary and predicted values
  list(n=winner,
       summary=summary(lm(y~xfit)),
       dat=data.frame(x=x[-seq_len(winner-1)][seq_len(win_length)],
                      y=y,
                      ypred=fit$fitted.values[,winner])
  )
}

all.equal(res0$ypred,res1$ypred)
#[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(optWinLinFit0(x,y,180),optWinLinFit1(x,y,180),times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                     expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# optWinLinFit0(x, y, 180) 30.90678 31.73952 31.83930 35.61465 35.90352    10
# optWinLinFit1(x, y, 180) 12.76270 14.70842 15.70562 16.06347 17.41174    10
```